# Replace character between two string in PCRE (Perl) syntax

Tags: regex, replace, pcre

How can I replace a special character between two special strings.

I have something like this:

```
"start 1
2-
G
23
end"
```

I want to have the following:

```
"start 1 2- G 23 end"
```

Only replace \n with space between "start and end"

```
Test1;Hello;"Text with more words";123
Test2;want;"start 
1-
76 end";123
Test3;Test;"It's a test";123
Test4;Hellp;"start
1234
good-
the end";1234
Test5;Test;"It's a test";123
```

Is it possible in notepad++?

Comment: And what is the problem? What do you mean by special strings?

Comment: How can I catch every line in a variable $1, $2 and so one to replace \n wir space character?

Comment: You don't need a regex, use a simple string replacement. (or better, a translation)

Comment: Just replace it? https://regex101.com/r/kJ9gV8/1

Comment: I mean, only between "start and end"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\bstart\b)(?:(?!\bend\b).)*\K\R
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY5oE9/1)

details:

```
(?:
    \G(?!\A)       # contiguous to a previous match
  |
    \bstart\b      # this is the first branch that matches
)
(?:(?!\bend\b).)*  # zero or more chars that are not a newline nor the start of the word "end"
\K                 # remove all on the left from the match result
\R                 # any newline sequence (\n or \r\n or \r)
```

Note: `(?:(?!\bend\b).)*` isn't very efficient, feel free to replace it by something better for your particular case.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. It it possible to use this in notepad++?

Comment: @cSteusloff: for notepad++, replace `\A` with `^`.

Answer (score 0):

Magic words are **lazy quantifier, lookaheads** and **single line mode**.
A solution for `PHP` (uses PCRE) would be:

```
<?php 
$string = __your_string_here__;

$regex = '~(?s)(?:start)(?<content>.*?)(?=end)(?s-)~';
# ~ delimiter
# (?s) starts single line mode - aka dot matches everything
# (?:start) captures start literally
# .*? matches everything lazily
# (?=end) positive lookahead
# (?s-) turn single line mode off
# ~ delimiter
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
$content = str_replace("\n", '', $matches["content"][1]);
echo $content; // 1234good-the 

?>
```